# How do I convert the String[] args array of a main method to a file path in the terminal?

Tags: java, string, file, terminal, program-entry-point

I have to somehow overwrite the String array args in my main function, in order to overwrite some files in my directory so if my directory was
C:\Users\User\Projects\Timsfolder
and in that directory I had another folder called importantFiles
in that folder another folder called filesToTest and in that folder are all the files I want to play around with, then how to I convert the args array of my main function into an array of length 3 with those paths as strings in order to later convert them into paths again using e.g. args[0] using the terminal?

Comment: `args[0].split("/")`? Or, better, don't use a `String[]` but use a `Path` instead: `Path path = Paths.get(args[0])`, from which you get the parts using `path.getName(n)`.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you have in mind here.  Are you saying you want to pass a single path `C:\Users\User\Projects\Timsfolder\importantFiles\ToTest` as `args[0]` and then break that up into `C:\Users\User\Projects\Timsfolder`, `importantFiles`, and `ToTest`?